# How to get the local port of a jdbc connection?

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

As far as I know when one establishes multiple `Connection` objects via JDBC to one database then each connection occupies a separate port on the machine where the `Connection` is established (they all connect to one port on the server where the DBMS is running).

I tried to extract the port that corresponds to the `Connection` objects. Unfortunately I did not find any way to do so.

---

Background: I'm doing performance analysis where I setup multiple clients which issue queries on the db. I'm logging the execution time of queries on the database server. In the resulting log I have - among others - information about the connection who initiated the query e.g. `localhost.localdomain:44760` I hope it is possible to use this information to map each query to the client or more precisely the `Connection` object who initiated the query (which is my ultimate goal and serves analysis purposes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run this select through the JDBC connection:

```
select inet_client_port()
```

More functions like that are in the manual: 
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html